# How I can keep a tabpages that I created with a button?

Tags: c#, addition, tabpage

Well I have a program and I work with a TabControl, I have a button and this create and add a new tabpages with a name that I sent through a textbox but my problem is that I need the tabpages to show info from a DB but when I restart the program the tabpages is not in the control, my question is how I can keep the tabpage that I already created, I need to put a register on DB?

This is a c# program (win form)

```
string x = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(x);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```

this is the code that used to create a tabpages

Comment: If I understand what you are saying you create the tab at run time by clicking on a button. If this is the case how do you expect the tab to still be there when the program restarts. For this to happen you will need to store each tab created somewhere and then read that storage to recreate them the next time the program is launched.

Comment: You need to define a format to store all the info needed to create them in the 1st place and then use it to re-create it from there. Unfortunately Controls can't be serialized or else xml would be a quick solution. Instead you can create a suit of serializable controls. If all you need is the name you should be able to get away with a lot less effort..

Comment: Also note that even if you manage to recreate controls they still will not have any useful events attached.. - So: What is the ultimate goal? re-create empty, useless tabpages? then all you need is to persist a list of strings. How exactly are yu displaying DB-info??

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes I can create a tab at run time when I clicking on a button. how can I store each tab, I need to use XML? or WPF with XAML? or I need to store a register on a DB or I need to create an specific kind of file to store a tab - I tried to do a system that will manage a graveyard, and I used the tabs to create sections. In a section I have a table 6*6 and I want that when I create a new section (tabpage) this new one will have a new empty table